# Get filesystem path of installed composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

How can get filesystem path of composer package?

composer.json example:

```
{

    "require" : {
        "codeception/codeception" : "@stable",
        "willdurand/geocoder": "*"
    }
}
```

example:
`$composer->getPath("\Geocoder\HttpAdapter\HttpAdapterInterface");`

and return it as:
`"/home/me/public_html/vendor/willdurand/geocoder/src/Geocoder/HttpAdapter"`

Answer (score 11):

*All of this is based on the assumption that you are actually talking about **packages** and not classes (which are mentioned in the example but are not asked for in the question).*

If you have the `Composer` object, you can get the path of the vendor directory from the `Config` object:

```
    $vendorPath = $composer->getConfig()->get('vendor-dir');
```

`$vendorPath` should now contain `/home/me/public_html/vendor/`.

It shouldn't be too hard to construct the rest of the path from there, as you already have the package name.

If this feels too flaky or you don't want to write the logic, there is another solution. You could fetch all packages, iterate until you find the right package and grab the path from it:

```
    $repositoryManager = $composer->getRepositoryManager();
    $installationManager = $composer->getInstallationManager();
    $localRepository = $repositoryManager->getLocalRepository();

    $packages = $localRepository->getPackages();
    foreach ($packages as $package) {
        if ($package->getName() === 'willdurand/geocoder') {
            $installPath = $installationManager->getInstallPath($package);
            break;
        }
    }
```

`$installPath` should now contain `/home/me/public_html/vendor/willdurand/geocoder`

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you! In a post-package-install script, we can write `$event->getComposer()->getInstallationManager()->getInstallPath($event->getOperation()->getPackage())` to get the install path of the installed package.

Comment: Curious where the `$composer` object comes from. How would you get hold of it?

Comment: @Jason If you want more details you should open a new questions but in short: [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md), [plugins](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md) and [installers](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md) are passed a Composer object before/when they are called.

Comment: It just seemed that `$composer` appeared out of thin air - I am just looking for clarification on what it actually is in this answer, rather than starting a whole new question. I'll read those articles, thanks.

Comment: How do I get the $composer object in my class?

Comment: @albertski I think you might want to ask a new question instead of adding that as a comment here... Too much depends on how and where you want the class for an answer to be easily added here.

Comment: @Potherca How did you get the $composer object in your example?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I'm guessing you got it like this example: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md#plugin-class

Answer (score 4):

Try ReflectionClass::getFileName - Gets the filename of the file in which the class has been defined.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php

Example:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass("\Geocoder\HttpAdapter\HttpAdapterInterface");
echo $reflector->getFileName();
```

Or you may use this:

```
$loader = require './vendor/autoload.php';
echo $loader->findFile("\Geocoder\HttpAdapter\HttpAdapterInterface");
```

The first method try to load class and return loaded class path. The second method return path from composer database without class autoload.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to get the vendor path without using the $composer object :

```
<?php

namespace MyPackage;

use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

class MyClass
{
    private function getVendorPath()
    {
        $reflector = new \ReflectionClass(ClassLoader::class);
        $vendorPath = preg_replace('/^(.*)\/composer\/ClassLoader\.php$/', '$1', $reflector->getFileName() );
        if($vendorPath && is_dir($vendorPath)) {
            return $vendorPath . '/';
        }
        throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to detect vendor path.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if the following is the correct way for this because composer is changing so fast.

If you run this command:

```
php /path/to/composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

it will create a classmap array in this file

```
vender/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

with this format "classname" => filepath.

So to find filepath of a given class is simple. If you create the script in your project's root folder, you can do this:

```
$classmap = require('vender/composer/autoload_classmap.php');
$filepath = $classmap[$classname]?: null;
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to know the filepath. If you just want to autoload classes, don't bother. The command `php /path/to/composer.phar dump-autoload -o` will make autoload very fast using composer's autoloader.