# Reuse a template from a composer.phar package

Tags: php, composer-php

On a very abstract example: I have some templates or files I want to load in Package A which are in a **third party** Package B which are both loaded in Application Z, by example:

```
{
  "name": "application/Z",
  "require": {
    "lib/A": "*"
  }  
}
```

And:

```
{
  "name": "lib/A",
  "require": {
    "lib\B": "*"
  }
}
```

Now I like to do something like this:

```
<?php
namespace lib\A;

class TemplateLoader {
 public function getInclude() {
    return file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/lib/b/templates/my.inc');
 }
}
```

This works, but using a relative path seems to be a bad idea, especially on unit testing, where the path begins with `'../vendor'`. So the path is not reliable.

Now my question: Is it possible to get the vendor path from composer like it is used in the autoloader? Or are there any best practices for implementations like this?

The obvious solution to create a function `\Lib\B\Templates::getIncludePath()` is not possible, cause I have no access to this library.

Comment: The only composer file which should be used runtime is `autoload.php`. The *obvious solution* is the right direction, but instead of returning path for includes, you'd better return the actual data/objects/variables etc.

Comment: I am looking for a solution like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714809/get-filesystem-path-of-installed-composer-package but without having to know, where the `autoload.php` is located. And it is about reusing static templates, I guess I have to change my question a bit in this direction.

Comment: Surely you know where autoload.php is located. You need to `require_once` it to make composer work at the first place. It returns an instance of ClassLoader, which you can use as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `lib/B`'s composer.json contains:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "lib\\B": "src/"
        }
    },
```

To answer the question, you can use composer's ClassLoader, so your `lib\A\TemplateLoader` may look like following:

```
namespace lib\A;

use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

class TemplateLoader {
    /** @var  ClassLoader  */
    protected $loader;

    public function __construct(ClassLoader $loader)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public function getInclude() {
        $libs = $this->loader->getPrefixes();
        if (!isset($libs['lib\\B'])) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Package lib/B is not loaded. Be sure it is included in composer.json and you ran 'compose install'.");
        }
        $path = $libs['lib\\B'][0];
        // At this point $path contains base path for classes in lib/B package,
        // depending on 'autoload' directive of lib/B's composer.json above.
        // In this example it is '/full/path/to/vendor/lib/B/src'

        $parts = explode('/', $path);
        array_pop($parts);
        $path = implode('/', $parts);

        return file_get_contents($path . '/templates/my.inc');
    }
}
```

### The correct way is to fork `lib/B` and add a template loader there:

```
namespace lib\B;

class TemplateLoader {
    public static function getTemplate($name) {
        return file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../templates/'.$name);
    }
}
```

So in `lib\A` it is straightforward:

```
namespace lib\A;

class TemplateLoader {
    public function getInclude() {
        return \lib\B\TemplateLoader::getTemplate('my.inc');
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. For using the ClassLoader, the application Z would have the requirement to store it into a variable and to init lib A with it. This is a solution I had in mind. But, the Second way to fork lib B is the way I'll go. Did not thought about forking it, before, thanks. It means some more work in the long run on maintaining it, but perhaps it get merged in the main branch in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As far as ways to find the composer `vendor-dir`, I've seen some attempts to do such a thing that are very fragile and I do not recommend.

- A very bad way to do it is make assumptions on the context by looking in two common locations for an `autoload.php`.
- A slightly better way is to use reflection against the results of `spl_autoload_functions` to determine the file the autoloader came from.

The ideal way would be to use `composer/composer` in your project as a library and find the package metadata in the local repository.

A very simplistic approach, which I would recommend, is to just configure the paths with your template loader. This could allow for you to have multiple third party libraries with different conventions on where they are placed in the repo.